# How do I find the sum of the following series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I have to find the sum of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1/((n+2)(2n+5))$. I performed partial fraction  decomposition and this is what I got:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{n+2}-\frac{2}{2n+5})$. So that makes my series:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{2}{7})+(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{2}{9})...$
How do I proceed from here?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: $\log(1+x)=x-x^2/2+x^3/3-+...$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**hint**

Put $$n+2=k$$
the sum becomes
$$\sum_{k=3}^{+\infty}(\frac 1k-\frac{2}{2k+1})=$$

$$2\sum_{k=3}^{+\infty}(\frac{1}{2k}-\frac{1}{2k+1})$$

Comment: Yes, now it "telescopes" and if OP needs help finihing they may google "telescoping series". [+1]

Comment: Thank you so much!! I will search telescoping series.

Comment: Are you sure, it is a telescoping series? I wrote down a few terms and it isn't canceling out!